# Reverse grep, find all non-match

Tags: bash, sed, grep, diff

I have two files that contain some similar data and some unique data.
I would like to find out what data appears in **first.txt** that does not appear in **second.txt**.

At first, I thought of using diff as the obvious option, but the order that the data appears in the files is important.

Here is what I mean. If the data is in order, then I get the info I expect.

```
macbook:labs alex$ cat first.txt
1
2
3
4
5
macbook:labs alex$ cat second.txt
1
3
5
macbook:labs alex$ diff first.txt second.txt
2d1
< 2
4d2
< 4
```

However, if we mix the order of the data inside the files up a little bit the output is quite different

```
macbook:labs alex$ cat first.txt
5
2
1
4
3
macbook:labs alex$ cat second.txt
3
1
5
macbook:labs alex$ diff first.txt second.txt
1,4d0
< 5
< 2
< 1
< 4
5a2,3
> 1
> 5
```

I also thought of using a grep, in a kind of loop

```
#!/bin/bash
a="first.txt"
b="second.txt"

for row in `cat $a`
  do grep $row $b
done
```

However, this will only tell me what is in **second**, that is also in **first**. I want to find out what is unique to **first**

Perhaps I don't understand it quite well enough, but the --inverse option of grep doesn't seem to help me either.

```
#!/bin/bash
a="first.txt"
b="second.txt"
for row in `cat $b`
 do
  grep -v $row $a
 done
```

Can someone shine any light on this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you have a choice you can use `comm` to find data unique to the first file like this:

```
comm -23 file1 file2
```

-23 suppresses the lines that are in both files, or only in file 2. The thing is the files need to be sorted first but if they are not you can pipe them through the `sort` command.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to find out what data appears in `first.txt` that does not appear in `second.txt`

You can use `grep -vf`:

```
grep -vFf second.txt first.txt

2
4
```